# Trouble selecting the objects

Tags: objects, selection-tools

When I try to select a house or the walls or any object that I have made, it just doesn't get selected until I click exactly in the middle. It's so annoying because I have to click few times to select the object that I want. I opened a new project and it works just fine anywhere I click on the object it gets selected. but in my main project file it just doesn't work. Maybe I turned on something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have hit <kbd>w</kbd> without noticing it.
It changes the selection mode to a selection circle that you can increase using the middle mouse button. If the circle is not over the origin point of your mesh/object, you won't be able to select it.

[image]

If I click now, I couldn't select the cube.

[image]

Press <kbd>w</kbd> again to change the cursor selection mode. Here it is in *Lasso* mode, meaning if you hold the left mouse button, you can draw an area to select multiple object.

[image]

You can press <kbd>w</kbd> until you get the normal cursor

Answer (score 1):

You can change the selection style by left clicking on the select mode for several seconds and a selection mode menu will appear.  But this may not be the issue you're encountering...

[image]

Comment: it worked thanks!